# How to compare two timestamp field in an entity in OFBiz

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have encountered a problem to make EntityCondition in OFBiz. I want to generate a condition which will compare two fields in an entity. Similar SQL query is like this.

```
select * from tableName where fromDate > lastUpdatedStamp
```

I have used

```
EntityCondition.makeCondition("fromDate", EntityComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN, EntityFieldValue.makeFieldValue("lastUpdatedStamp"))
```

But it does not help. When I try to execute this it says

`Key(0), with value (fromDate > lastUpdatedStamp) is not a string`. Do anyone know how this can be achive in OFBiz?

Comment: This particular error occures when the field is not present in the table. The entitycondition is right but I am looking fromDate field in different table where this field is not present.